# iOS timing every ms

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, clock

I am trying to interface through the microphone jack on the iPhone.

I need to update 15 bits constantly and I'm wondering if the best way to do this would be as follows:

I have a 16ms 'frame'. The first 1ms is the START bit and it is 500mV. The next 15ms are either 0V or 250mV. It would then repeat with the START bit.

Can I accurately scan this quickly on iOS?

Comment: wasn't thinking...I meant it as a millisecond tag which makes more sense but is still probably not a relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, [no](http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/). The best you can get is about every 5ms but that's nowhere near stable enough to write an app around it. A safe margin is 30ms or so (once per 'frame' akin to a video framerate of 30fps).

Comment: I believe the best you can get is 60 hz (fps) as long as you are not bogging down your main loop.  CADisplayLink will fire every frame and iOS tries its best to run at 60 frames per second.  Or you can just add your logic to the main run loop and have it get called every time the run loop repeats (again, once every frame @ 60 fps as long as you don't block the main thread).  Is this wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, that seems to have been addressed in the article you linked to.